# creating a page with multiple views in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

ok, I am new to CakePhp. I haven't used any framework before and this is my first time.
The question that I have is how to put multiple views on a single page.
For example on a typical homepage, I will have newsfeed, as well as form for login, chatbox etc.
What i understand is each of them will have different controller and views. 
Therefore how do I put them together ?
Thanks.

Comment: Just to clarify a bit, a typical page load involves only one controller and one view (+ eventually some elements). But to aggregate data from different sources the controller would use many models, and a login form would probably point to another controller and action. A chatbox would probably requires another controler, but it would be done through Ajax and thus would be different page loads.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can reuse views. The best is to use elements. Take a look at:

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1081/Elements

The second way to use requestAction. Take a look at:
http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/gwoo/2007/04/12/creating-reusable-elements-with-requestaction