# cakephp 3.0.x extending view?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm using cakephp 3.0.x and I wanna make a page that has multiple views in it. E.g. If I have these index.ctp from other Templates like below

- Template/Customers/index.ctp
- Template/Orders/index.ctp

i want to make a page say Template/Main/index.ctp. That contains the index.ctp from Customers and Orders. Essentially, views in a view (view-ception :P ). Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8626524/creating-a-page-with-multiple-views-in-cakephp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can do this if you use [View Elements](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views.html#elements).

The best way to do this would be to create an Element template for the customers index template and then output this in both your Customers/index and Main/index templates like this:-

```
// Output Template/Element/customers.ctp
echo $this->Element('customers');
```

The Element template will inherit variables from the calling template, but you can also pass variables to it. For example, if you need to have a `$data` variable but have set this in your Controller as `$customers`:-

```
echo $this->Element('customers', ['data' => $customers]);
```

If rather than create an actual Element View template you just want to reuse your existing Customers/index template as is you can still output it using `$this->Element()` in your Main/index template:-

```
// Output Template/Customers/index.ctp
echo $this->Element('../Customers/index');
```

Personally I'd avoid doing this and opt for the first example and modify your existing Customers/index to use an Element as it will make the code more maintainable in the future.

Comment: Sweet, I'll give this a shot tonight after work and report the result. Thanks!